# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable (math-equation problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, ipython

I'm trying use this equation as part of my equation. It calculates new velocity based on previous velocity and positions. It ran fine when I declare is as function

```
def new_velocity(part, pop):
   r1 = random.random()
   r2 = random.random()
   vel = part[2]
   new_v = w*np.array(vel) + c1*r1*(np.array(pbest(part))-np.array(part[1])) + c2*r2(np.array(gbest(pop))-np.array(part[1]))
   return new_v
```

But when I tried to use it with this code below :

```
pop = population(20)
p = pop[0]
vel = p[2]
newv = new_velocity(p,pop)
print(p)
print(vel)
print(newv)
```

It spilled an error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-721e9d90164a> in <module>
      2 p = pop[0]
      3 vel = p[2]
----> 4 newv = new_velocity(p,pop)
      5 print(p)
      6 print(vel)

<ipython-input-100-3d3e0223d8d9> in new_velocity(part, pop)
      3   r2 = random.random()
      4   vel = part[2]
----> 5   new_v = w*np.array(vel) + c1*r1*(np.array(pbest(part))-np.array(part[1])) + c2*r2(np.array(gbest(pop))-np.array(part[1]))
      6   return new_v

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I assumed it's math-related because it's pointing out to the equation.

Comment: You should rewrite your function to take the inputs individually,
eg at the moment your passing lists or tuples from population and its hard to see whats being called as your grabbing slices of this in the formula

Comment: This is usually caused by forgetting a `*` somewhere. I would check whether any of pbest, r2, or gbest are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

mabye missing a "*"

```py
def new_velocity(part, pop):
   r1 = random.random()
   r2 = random.random()
   vel = part[2]
   new_v = w*np.array(vel) + c1*r1*(np.array(pbest(part))-np.array(part[1])) + c2*r2*(np.array(gbest(pop))-np.array(part[1]))
   return new_v
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the `*` between r2 and the paren

```
c2*r2(np.array(gbest(pop))
```

should be

```
c2*r2*(np.array(gbest(pop))
```

I don't know if that's what you meants, but r2 is definitely a float , and therefore not callable as a function, and considering the pattern on the 1st part of the equation I assume that's what is wrong here.